# Constantly check if date is in the past

Tags: javascript

I want to check if selected date is in the past in 'for loop'. But if I use 'for loop' it stops other code from running. How can I constantly check if date is in the past and not stopping other code from running?

```
for (var now = new Date();;) {
   if (selectedDate < now) { 
      // some code
   }
}

console.log('1') // code that's not running.
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is fully synchronous and single-threaded. Therefore, your code is getting "locked-up" or stuck at the `for` loop you have referenced.

You need to use `setInterval`. For example:

```js
// For demonstration purposes.
var selectedDate = new Date();

// The code inside of this function will run every 1 second (or 1,000 milliseconds)
setInterval(function () {
   var now = new Date();
   if (selectedDate < now) { 
      console.log("Selected date is in the past!");
  }
}, 1000);

console.log('1') // This code runs now because JavaScript is not caught executing the for loop.
```

Comment: Instead of IF put while(true) { ... }, and that is the second condition ('Constantly checking'), so that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of solutions for resolve this problem. You can use an Observable if ou use RXJS. Else you can use a simple interval with an arrow function or a simple funtion and define repeat time interval in millisecond :

```
setInterval(repeatFunc,intervalInMillisecond);
```